# Full screen through batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch script under Windows. When anyone will click on that script I want the command window to become full screen like we do by keyboard shortcut `[Alt+Enter]`.

Can it be done automatically using any command in batch file?

Comment: I believe that starting with Vista, Windows doesn't support the full screen mode anymore. So I think that even if it's possible, it won't be a robust solution.

Comment: @Michael, Actually, full-screen cmd is still supported in Windows 7 (so I assume it's still supported in Vista).

Comment: @Michael: It's not supported with WDDM drivers, but old display drivers should still be able to use it.

Comment: @joey: thanks for the clarification - if I could edit my comment, I'd change it to say something more like "Windows support for full screen mode is spotty starting with Vista; you might not be able to depend on it being there".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows XP, you need to start your program maximized (but not full screen) via "start /max" as follows:

```
start "Winow Title" /MAX "C:\batches\myfile.bat"
```

This command would be inside your original batch file, and call the real bath file.

I don't think there's a way to change the full screen-ness of an executing "cmd" command *from within a batch file* absent someone writing a special app to do so by emulating sending `Alt+Enter` to the parent process.

In Windows 7 (and probably Vista) you must run inside XP virtual machine for full screen mode.

Comment: That will only start it maximized, though, not full-screen.

Comment: @Joey - Yikes. Me blind (I started my full screen app and didn't notice the title bar. DUH).

Answer (score 3):

There is none. You can write a small program doing so for you, though. There is the [SetConsoleDisplayMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686028%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: I want it in batch file .. not in vc++