# start batch file in fullscreen mode

Tags: batch-file, fullscreen

How can I start a batch file in full-screen mode?  I know that this question was asked before, but it wasn't actually answered.

unfortunately, I don't know reverse engineering, so I cant decompile the code.

Here is something I tested:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start cmd.exe
%sendkeys% "(%{enter})"
goto :EOF
@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

The idea is that it starts a cmd window, and (this part of the code `%sendkeys% "(%{enter})"`) is supposed to simulate the user pressing [alt] + [enter].  But it doesn't work.

I wrote a little c# tool to send an alt+enter to the cmd window, but I'm looking for an internal method.

Comment: Did you tried this way?
 1. Open a cmd window
 2. Right click the title bar
 3. Check full screen on the Options tab
 4. Save settings

http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=67226.0

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information.  I was looking for a bit of code that would do the job.  I also tried the `sendkeys` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914858/full-screen-through-batch-command

Comment: If Arachne is a bat file, then you don't need "reverse engineering". If it's not, then it's irrelevant.

Comment: note that not every cmd.exe versions (like the one in Windows 7) support running in fullscreen. You may need a 3rd party console for that

Answer (score 1):

If `sendkeys` parameter for "Alt-Enter" should be "%{enter}", then this line:

```
%sendkeys% "(%{enter})"
```

... should have not parentheses and there is one percent sign missing. Try:

```
%sendkeys% "%%{enter}"
```

See the example for "Alt-V" at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502011/is-it-possible-to-display-the-html-code-of-a-webpage-in-a-batch-file/23508061#23508061)

Answer (score 0):

I made an autoIT script, extremely simple.

```
Run("cmd.exe")
sleep (1000)
Send("!{enter}")
```

Unfortunately, this isn't what I want.  I was looking for more of an actual command, not some other 3d party program.

:: edit

here: [This is a link to the compiled 1 line skiddy script that I made.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvnerfhok40b6kj/fullscreen.exe)

Its a command line tool, so all you have to do is type `fullscreen` in a cmd window to **toggle** fullscreen mode.

In case you don't know how to use a command line tool, you have to be in the same directory as the file.