# How to fullscreen cmd on startup

Tags: batch-file, cmd, fullscreen, startup

I am trying to full screen cmd when the computer starts and no I am not looking for mode 1000 or 800 I mean actually full screen. To do this you must press alt+enter but I don't know how to do this when the computer starts. Please help.
EDIT:
Win 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [start batch file in fullscreen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728958/start-batch-file-in-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: Ken I did go to your link but there was nothing of use the code doesn't work

Comment: Maybe [Shell Launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt571994(v=vs.85).aspx) is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Autohotkey, this script will work.

```
Run cmd.exe
Send !{ENTER}
```

Save it as maximize.ahk and run it at startup.

--

Aside: I got pretty close using Batch+Jscript, but I couldn't get cmd win Win10 to recognize ALT. It recognizes pretty much every other key, though. I just thought I'd share just in case.

```
@if (@O)==(@O) @
@CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
@exit /b @end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("%~");
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This script is still EXTREMELY useful.

Comment: One quick thing how do you get it to work properly because when I add batch script at the end it still thinks I am trying to use JS

Comment: Put your batch script between the `@if` and `@exit`. The CScript line is where it puts itself into the JScript interpreter.